# SASS and Jekyll integration

Tags: ruby, sass, jekyll

I'm just wondering if there is a way to integrate SASS into Jekyll. All that I need is an automatic .scss compilation into .css when I launch Jekyll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with compiling assets when you launch (which I take to mean run) `jekyll`.  The whole point of running `jekyll` is to pre-compile your site, which is **good** for performance.

As for asset conversion-- there are many plugins available that focus on this.  I like the [Jekyll Asset Pipeline](http://www.matthodan.com/2012/11/22/jekyll-asset-pipeline.html) gem, which supports any language (e.g. Scss, Less, CoffeeScript, Erb, etc.) and has a bunch of features (e.g. asset tagging, compression, gzipping, etc.) that set it apart.  It also seems to be the fastest growing Jekyll-related gem these days, which I take to mean that it is gaining traction in the community.

Comment: `jekyll-asset-pipeline` appears to be dead.  No development on public git repository in five months, though 0.1.6 was released without being pushed to public repository.  It's incompatible with the latest `jekyll` versions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep it as simple as `compass watch` you can use the [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) gem along with [guard-jekyll](https://github.com/therabidbanana/guard-jekyll) and [guard-compass](https://github.com/guard/guard-compass) (and if you like style injection, [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload)).

Guard bundles multiple 'watch' actions under a single terminal window, and is much easier to set up than a robust asset pipeline. Install the gems, configure the `.guardfile` according to the guard-compass and guard-jekyll instructions, `cd` to your directory and type `guard`. Any time a relevant file changes your sass files and/or jekyll site will be recompiled.

Answer (score 3):

Native Sass, and CoffeeScript, processing debuted in Jekyll v2.0:

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/#sassscss

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: I am the lead dev behind this project.

The easiest way I've seen to setup Sass with Jekyll is with [`jekyll-compass`](https://github.com/mscharley/jekyll-compass). This gem will do exactly as you describe: Any time jekyll builds your website (`jekyll build`, `jekyll serve`, etc) your Sass will be compiled into the output folder along with the rest of your website. Check out the readme linked above for full usage details.

There's also some work under way currently by the Jekyll guys to get Sass support into the core of Jekyll so that everyone will have at least basic access to Sass and the wonderful feature-set it provides.